# Python regular expression for extracting month and year

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I want to extract month and year from string. For example:

If I have a string `From August 2017 - September 2018` then I should get `'August 2017'` and `'September 2018'` as two groups. I tried the following:

```
import re

regex = r'(\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3}\b-)?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?(\d{1,2}\D?)?\D?((19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})'
experience = re.findall(regex, 'August 2017 - Sep 2018')
print(experience)
```

This returns `[('', '', '20', '17', ''), ('', '', '20', '18', '')]`

I also tried **re.search**:

```
import re

regex = r'(\b\d{1,2}\D{0,3}\b-)?\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\D?(\d{1,2}\D?)?\D?((19[7-9]\d|20\d{2})|\d{2})'
experience = re.search(regex, 'August 2017 - Sep 2018')
print(experience.group())
```

This returns only `August 2017`

Can we have some regex to extract both the dates?

Comment: What about this `(?P<fmonth>\w+.\d+)\s+\-\s+(?P<smonth>\w+.\d+)`?

Comment: Rather than trying to cram everything into the regex, it's going to be easier and more legible to use simpler regex and then parse the data with `datetime.strptime` or `dateutil.parser.parse_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xtRoTx/3).

```
import re

string = "From August 2017 - September 2018"
month = re.search("(?P<fmonth>\w+.\d+)\s+\-\s+(?P<smonth>\w+.\d+)", string)
month = month.groups()

print (month)
```

Output:

```
('August 2017', 'September 2018')
```

Comment: @Yusufn thanks this works like charm. Also can we print out the same output if there is `to` in between two dates instead of `-` ? For example: `"From August 2017 to September 2018"`

Comment: Then change the regex into `(?P<fmonth>\w+.\d+)\s+\D+\s+(?P<smonth>\D+.\d+)`

Comment: That works. Thanks. The above regex was also capturing `May,2017` so I tuned it to: `(?P<fmonth>\w+\s\d+)\s+\D+\s+(?P<smonth>\D+\s\d+)`. Posting this as anyone with the same problem can have solution.