# Regular Expression for month and year excluding some words

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression able to handle inputs like bellow to extract month and year while handling all these different cases and extract the 2 groups (start and end) like this:

```
From August 2017 - September 2018   (output: {August 2017},{September 2018})
From August to September 2018       (output: {August},{September 2018})
July 2009 - August 2019             (output: {July 2009},{August 2019})
De Aout 2019 a July 2020            (output: {Aout 2019},{July 2020})
De Juillet a Aout 2020              (output: {Juillet},{Aout 2020})
Juillet - Aout 2019                 (output: {Juillet},{Aout 2019})
Juillet a Aout 2019                 (output: {Juillet},{Aout 2019})
```

I found this regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252242/python-regular-expression-for-extracting-month-and-year) which does a good job ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/xtRoTx/5)):

```
(?P<fmonth>\w+.\d*)\s+\D+\s+(?P<smonth>\D+.\d+)
```

But the problem with it is that it does not handle these 2 cases where there is no year in the first part:

```
De Juillet a Aout 2020
From August to September 2018
```

I think it's missing a part to exclude/ignore specific words like "From" and "De".

Any ideas or solutions ?

Comment: If you're willing to go beyond regex, might I suggest Duckling - https://github.com/facebook/duckling? You can also try it out here - https://duckling.wit.ai/. It handles From August to September 2018 nicely.

Comment: Might require some tweaking but it's a good start: `(\w+(?: \d{4})?) (?:-|to|a) (\w+ \d{4})`. See it here: https://regex101.com/r/i8BgX9/1

Comment: @borancar  I tried Duckling .. It's a great suggestion. I've never seen it before. but unfortunately it didn't handle french very well which is important in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `\D+` is a very generic pattern, it matches `August to` in `From August to September 2018`, i.e. any 1+ non-digit symbols. Also, `\w` matches letters, digits and `_`s, it may be more appropriate to only match letters when you need to match month names, and for that, all you need is to subtract `\d` and `_` from it (`[^\W\d_]`).

You may use a bit more precise regex:

```
(?P<fmonth>[^\W\d_]+(?:\W+\d+)?)\s+(?:to|a|-)\s+(?P<smonth>[^\W\d_]+\W+\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UTSu39/1)

**Details**

- `(?P<fmonth>[^\W\d_]+(?:\W+\d+)?)` - *fmonth* group: 1+ letters and an optional sequence of 1+ non-word chars followed with 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:to|a|-)` - `to`, `a` or `-`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<smonth>[^\W\d_]+\W+\d+)` - *smonth* group: 1+ letters, 1+ non-word chars, 1+ digits